# can not connect to remote SQL Server Analysis Service (SSAS)

Tags: ssas

If disabling the Firewall or opening the 2382 or 2383 port is not making any sense to make connection to the SSAS server then, there could be below issue.... Which I have discovered by spending lot of time research.....

To connect to SSAS, SSAS server must have a domain(active directory) installed on it. The client machine from which you want to access the SSAS must have in the same domain of SSAS server. If the SSAS server have a no domain, i.e. it is in the default domain (means in WORKGROUP) & the client machine is also in the "WORKGROUP". Then for making connection to SSAS, you have to create same user(with same password) on both the machine (on client & SSAS server). After that you have to add that user in the SSAS-Property-Security access. After that you have to login with the newly created user on the client machine & try for making connection to SSAS.

Comment: Is this a question or are you sharing your findings with the community?

Comment: You could have better answered your own question, SSAS only supports windows authentication. Creating user with same name, and password is a loophole which you can use but that may not work if you are using role based security in SSAS.